# Proper SE site to ask about how to bypass Iran's internet restrictions for Google access

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have one question about the Internet problem in Iran which I asked on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008333/how-to-bypass-iran-intranet-restrictions-for-google-access-and). It was closed as an off-topic question, so where I can ask it?

This is the content:

> [The government restricted all the international internet connections for almost 70 Millions Iranian people for 7 days at November of 2019](https://www.wired.com/story/iran-internet-shutoff/) and for 7 days almost all Iranian people in Iran country have not access to international internet like google and ... but(our political men are crazy !!! happy that we have not no  political women almost!!!) .
>
> [image]
>
> I have heard the cost of doing this is 1 billion  US‌ Dollar for one year by help of [DLP](http://www.dlpcommllc.com/) Italian communities LCC, SO i think The DLP Engineers must know what can we do now?
>
> How is it possible bypass internet restriction in Iran to get access to to some simple sites like google.
>
> Also if this is not possible how we could be in contact with each other when we don't have international connection like these days or when the internet totally banned by government?
>
> I found some apps like [firechat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opengarden.firechat&hl=en),
>
> Is this possible to be done by block-chain technology?
>
> Is this possible to create some app like torrent by converting every mobiles phone to one server for communication between each other ?

Comment: Re *"intranet restrictions"*: Don't you mean *"Internet restrictions"*?

Comment: Yanno. there's not much they can do if they cut out *all* of the internet. Like literally, turn off the main trunk connections out of the country.

Comment: Are you interested in HAM radio perhaps? The government can't take that down and the range is hundreds of kilometers.

Comment: Thanks @Mast i was thinking is it possible to combine some apps like Signal or Firechat to communicate with HAM Radio for more area coverage and is the HAM Radio station location  could be discover  by government? and if yes, what when it be mobile at a car?

Comment: HAM from a car is perfectly possible, but the range and throughput will suffer due to less power.

Comment: So you want to ask for good VPN?

Answer (score 16):

It is possible that your post may be on-topic at the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site. They have quite a few questions and a lot of them do cover Internet censorship by governments.

Answer (score 8):

> How is it possible bypass Internet restriction in Iran to get access to some simple sites like Google.

When out of country access is permitted there's an answer on [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/q/429358/419485) where user [Paul](https://superuser.com/a/429387/419485) suggests [Openvpn-ALS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/). So, it is on-topic there and there's an answer.

If that doesn't answer your question you can ask a new one.

When out of country access is turned off, it's off. There are no legal methods.

From [NetBlocks.org](https://netblocks.org/reports/internet-restored-in-iran-after-protest-shutdown-dAmqddA9), Nov 23, 2019:

> "... Current connectivity levels have risen to 64% after earlier flatlining at 5% for several days. Mobile internet remains generally unavailable. ...".

It looks like a hole was found on the 17th, which was quickly plugged.

[image: Internet shut off, except for a hole that was quickly patched.]